# How to Update View from ViewModel using MVVMCross and Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Am new to MVVMCross with xamarin.android so little struck up with a scenario. I have a fab and mvx.recyclerview inside a fragment. so when i click on this fab it will make the recyclerview scroll by a row.

i.e

```
void onclick(sender object ,eventargs e)
{
   mrecyclerview.SmoothScrollToPosition(somevariable++); // do something.
}
```

this is breaking mvvm pattern, so is there any way or method in the MVVM Cross which i can use to listen back to the View from ViewModel.

fab.click binding with ICommand => viewmodel => view=> updatescroll().

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, since the `ViewModel` should not know about the `View`, you should not call any method of it.

I would propose an `event` in your `ViewModel` where your `View` can subscribe. So you call your `event` something like `FabClickDone` and your view does what ever it wants, when this event occured. In your case scrolling.

Here is an code example for your ViewModel:

```
public delegate void FabClickDoneEvent(object sender, EventArgs args);
public event FabClickDoneEvent FabClickDone;

protected virtual void OnFabClickDone()
{
    FabClickDone?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

You then just call it by

```
void onclick(sender object , eventargs e)
{
    // Do something inside your viewmodel
    // ...
    OnFabClickDone();
}
```

In your View constructor subscribe to this event:

```
ViewModel.FabClickDone += ViewModel_FabClickDone;
```

And create a method where you want to do your scrolling

```
void ViewModel_FabClickDone(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mrecyclerview.SmoothScrollToPosition(somevariable++); // do something.
}
```

Since you're using MVVMcross I would suggest you using a command, where you call OnFabClickDone();

Comment: Probably I'm kinda late but my view constructor can't see `.FabClickDone` event field

Comment: @DanilGholtsman - try `((MyViewModelClass)BindingContext).FabClickDone`.

Comment: ... actually in mvvmcross, `protected override void OnViewModelSet() { base.OnViewModelSet(); var vm = ViewModel as MyViewModelClass; vm.FabClickDone += ... }`.

Comment: You can use EventHandler delegate instead of FabClickDoneEvent